# Querystring manipulation of email Address in PHP

Tags: php, url, query-string

I am using some third party application (email2http) which will send me emailID, body and message.
I unable to retrieve the email ID properly due to my name is appended on it and enclosed with < and >.
Here is the querystring I am getting.

test.php?from=Ajay+Reddy &subject=cx&body=somebody

When I print the from variable in PHP it just returns the name and not email ID.

$from = $_GET['from'];
echo $from;

//output 
Ajay Reddy

Please suggest me how can I get the emailID also.

I dont want to use post method due to my testing and debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine. You forgot to use `htmlentities()` in your debugging.

Comment: thanks I was using html_entity_decode, thats why it didnt work. Now it works